# Copy data from a table in a schema to another table in another schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to copy the data from a table in a schema to another table in another schema. The 2 tables have the same columns. I tried

```
SET @Script = 'SELECT * FROM application_params.' + @tableName + ' INSERT INTO temp_application_params.' +@tableName
Exec  sp_executesql @Script
```

Where @tablename is a variable containing the table's name. The tables' names are the same. But these instructions don't copy the data, the second table remains empty. What is the problem ?

Comment: How does this even run?, do you know that the right syntax would be `INSERT INTO table SELECT ... FROM other_table`

Comment: @Lamak: I also tried this way, but it doesn't work

Comment: what does `doesn't work` means here?, the query you posted should've given you an error

Comment: Why the dynamic sql for this? A simple insert select pattern should do this with no issue.

Comment: I wquld strongly advise you against using select * as your insert. You should explicitly name the columns to avoid future problems when the table changes.

Comment: I don't know the name of columns, I only know that the columns are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the target table exists:

```
INSERT INTO targetTable
SELECT * FROM [sourceserver].[sourcedatabase].[dbo].[sourceTable]
```

If the target table does not exists:

```
select * into targetTable from [sourceserver].[sourcedatabase].[dbo].[sourceTable]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the second table exist

```
Set @script = 'insert into schema2.' + @tablename + ' select * from schema1.' + @tablename
```

If the second table DOES NOT exist

```
Set @script = 'select * into schema2.' + @tablename + ' from schema1.' + @tablename
```

Then

```
Exec sp_executesql @script
```